# How to get cookie value from CGI::Cookie.parse?

Tags: ruby, cookies, cgi

How can I get a reasonable cookie value using only standard libraries from Ruby 2.7? According to the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/Cookie.html), `#value` is supposed to return a value or a list of values, but clearly it's not the case. `c.value` returns `c`

```rb
$ docker run --rm -it library/ruby:2.7
require 'cgi'
c = CGI::Cookie.parse('test=foo')['test']
# => #<CGI::Cookie: "test=foo; path=">
p c.value
# => #<CGI::Cookie: "test=foo; path=">
c.equal? c.value
# => true
# Please, what?
```

Expected result: `foo` (if www-encoded like `%66%6f%6f`, I want the decoded result `foo`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent class of `CGI::Cookie` is `Array`. Now we can figure it out:

```
>> c = CGI::Cookie.parse('test=%66%6f%6f')['test']
=> #<CGI::Cookie: "test=foo; path=">
>> c.size
=> 1
>> c.first
=> "foo"
>> c[0]
=> "foo"
```

Comment: Interesting. Never imagined it `is_a? Array`.